# Angular | How to dynamically change ngTemplateOutlet for responsive purpose

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-flex-layout

I'm using Angular with [Angular Flexbox](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) to create a web application.

I use a lot of `ng-templates` for html code blocks that are used multiple times in order to comply with DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

**Question:** Is it possible to change the `ngTemplateOutlet` value based on the width of the screen?

Example:

```
<ng-template #fullWidthContainer>
  <!-- code left out on purpose -->
</ng-template>

<ng-template #halfWidthContainer>
  <!-- code left out on purpose -->
</ng-template>

<!-- If width is less than medium: use 'fullWidthContainer', otherwise go with 'halfWidthContainer' -->
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="halfWidthContainer" [ngTemplateOutlet.lt-md]="fullWidthContainer"></ng-template>
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="halfWidthContainer" [ngTemplateOutlet.lt-md]="fullWidthContainer"></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    this.width = event.target.innerWidth;
}
```

Listen to the window resize event in your component and get the width of the window and then based on that width you cand render your halfWidthContainer or fullWidthContainer.

```
<!-- If width is less than medium: use 'fullWidthContainer', otherwise go with 'halfWidthContainer' -->
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="(width < 300) ? fullwidthContainer : halfWidthContainer" ></ng-template>
```